# NullPointerException Error while parsing the string in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is my code to parse a string which comes in the format of #some headers#val1,val2,val3,val4,val5#. So, i tried to parse the vals out of the format. I'm getting NullPointerException on the last line of the submitted code. Anyone kindly help to resolve this issue

```
String stringVal = "formatted text as mentioned above";

System.out.println("In string parser");
String delimit = "#";
int limit = 4;
output = stringVal.split(delimit, limit);
System.out.println("after split : "+ output[2]);

DataVals = output[2].split(",", 6);
System.out.println("DataVals :"+Arrays.toString(DataVals));
nCtrlNo[j] = DataVals[0];   //-----> error occurs on this line
```

Class members DataVals & nCtrlNo defined as

```
static String[] DataVals;
static String[]  nCtrlNo;
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't initialize `nCtrlNo`.

Comment: nCtrlNo[j] is not getting the value..try using a debugger..Also check if it is initialized properly

Comment: @Akshay public static String[] nCtrlNo = null;  ????

Comment: try initializing as public static String[] nCtrNo = new String[size]; // give some "size"

Comment: Thank you exactly i have tried the same; I tried to initialize with definite size of 25. it stops throwing null pointer exception.